# DB2 SQL query to remove duplicates on one column and then provide the sum of duplicates on another column within the new subset

Tags: sql, join, db2, filtering

With the following query:

```
SELECT ADSTAT, ADASNO, ORDERNO FROM  BLUEWATER ORDER BY ADASNO;
```

I can get the following:

```
ADSTAT  ADASNO     ORDERNO                                                                                                                                     
40      ASN123   40303020                                                                                                                                    
40      ASN123   40303020                                                                                                                                    
30      ASN124   40303021                                                                                                                                    
30      ASN124   40303021                                                                                                                                    
30      ASN125   40303021
```

I am looking for a query that will:

(1) consider distinct / eliminate any duplicate ADASNO row (whichever is insignificant as long as ADASNO has no duplicates) (2) and ONLY then creates a fourth column showing the total count for duplicate ORDERNO records that exist (Not in the table overall but within the new subset that has eliminated duplicate ADASNO records).

The target database is DB2. I currently don't know what version but will seek to ascertain this although I am assuming not a recent version.

My goal is a query that produces the following:

```
ADSTAT  ADASNO     ORDERNO  ORDERNOTOTAL                                                                                                                    
40      ASN123   40303020    1                                                                                                                               
30      ASN124   40303021    2                                                                                                                               
30      ASN125   40303021    2
```

The solution needs to avoid use of the PARTITION keyword as this version of DB2 doesn't accept it.

I am still trying to establish the version of DB2 database, suffice to say it is not that recent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can do it with CTE or temporary table, as PARTITION keyword can't be used

```
with temp1 as (
SELECT ADASNO, MAX(adstat) as ADSTAT, MAX(ORDERNO) as ORDERNO
FROM BLUEWATER
group by ADASNO),
temp2 as ( select ADSTAT, COUNT(ORDERNO) as Count FROM temp1 GROUP BY ADSTAT)
SELECT temp1.ADASNO, temp1.ADSTAT, temp1.ORDERNO, temp2.Count
FROM temp1
join temp2
on temp1.ADSTAT = temp2.ADSTAT
```